# Gray desktop after usual upgrade in Xubuntu 14.04

Tags: xubuntu, xfdesktop

After an update a couple of days ago, my desktop is gone and a gray screen is now in it's place. No usual icons and if I try to click with the right mouse button nothing happens. However, the top menu is functional. Following a tip, I installed the last "xfdesktop" version, just as bellow:

xfdesktop --version
This is xfdesktop version 4.12.2, running on Xfce 4.12.
Built with GTK+ 2.24.23, linked with GTK+ 2.24.23.
Build options:
Desktop Menu: enabled
Desktop Icons: enabled
Desktop File Icons: enabled

My OS details:

lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS
Release: 14.04
Codename: trusty

uname -a
Linux atpc 4.2.0-42-generic #49~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jun 29 20:22:11 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Any light? Thanks a lot.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As pointed here (https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2331480) at the Ubuntu Forum:

This one makes sure xfdesktop isn't running

```
xfdesktop --quit
```

And this one tries to start xfdesktop

```
xfdesktop --disable-wm-check
```

Although the problem persisted after the restart, it seems that after the last new upgrade the bug was solved.